# Prove there isn't a non-zero nilpotent element of a finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-rings

> Let $(A, +, \cdot)$ be a finite ring with $n$ elements having the property: $x^n
>  \ne1, \forall x \ne 1, x \in A$. Prove $0$ is the only nilpotent
>   element of $A$.

---

**My attempt**

Suppose there is $y \in A, y \ne 0$ so that $y^k = 0$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0, 1\}$, $k$ minimal. The idea might be to contradict the minimality of $k$ by constructing a $k' \lt k$, having the same property as $k$ has, but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer, it works if $\# A$ is prime or the characteristic of $A$ is prime.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Yes, but the idea still might work with some modifications. No problem, we all make mistakes. Thanks for your involvement.

Comment: Probably, the 'proof' used all the right ingredients, finiteness leads to a finite characteristic and this power trick exploits the condition that $x^n\neq 1$ for all $x\neq 1$.

Comment: I haven't found it yet, so I'm going to post the proof in case the characteristic of $A$ is prime, maybe someone sees how to modify the argument (if at all possible). Since $A$ is finite, $n=\text{char}(A)\mid \#A$. Suppose that $y^k=0$ for some $y\neq 0$ and $k>1$. Assume that $n$ is a prime number. Then $y^{n}+1=(y+1)^n\neq 1$ since $y+1\neq 1$. More generally,  $y^{n^{m}}+1=(y+1)^{n^m}\neq 1$. Hence $y^{n^m}\neq 0$ for all $m$. This contradicts the fact that $y^k=0$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the proof. Using Newton's binomial : $(y^{k-1} + 1)^n = y^k \cdot a + ny^{k-1} + 1 = 1 \tag 1$

Therefore $y^{k-1}=0$ contradiction with $k$ minimality.

I followed an idea provided by @Mathematician 42

Comment: Correct, nice, that was the modification that was needed.